# sending an email with attachment using python script

Tags: python

I'm using the code given in tutorialspoint.com for sending an email with an attatchment. The code works fine and i'm recieving emails as well but the problem is when i upload a text file which looks like this:

```
|Checks|     |Status|        |Remarks|                                                                                           

ECHConnect   checked         The model is completely connected


ECHPenetra   checked         EChPenet: 2436 elements penetrate/touch each other


ECHCharlen   not_checked     

ECHCoincid   checked         No coincident elements


ECHEdgeLen   checked         Shortest edge length = 1.


EMSameNorm   checked         No elements have to be reoriented


EEBeam       checked         34 elements modified according to window settings


Outline      checked         Free edges displayed in green
```

the text file which i recieve is pretty messed up with the indentation. But i want to be exactly similar to this. How can i do that? The code which i used is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import smtplib
import base64

filename = "/home/hamanda/Desktop/transfer/new_result.txt"

# Read a file and encode it into base64 format
fo = open(filename, "rb")
filecontent = fo.read()
encodedcontent = base64.b64encode(filecontent)

sender = 'harisyam.manda@daimler.com'
reciever ='harisyam.manda@daimler.com' 

marker = "AUNIQUEMARKER"

body ="""
This is a test email to send an attachement.
"""
# Define the main headers.
part1 = """From: From Person <harisyam.manda@daimler.com>
To: To Person <harisyam.manda@daimler.com>
Subject: Sending Attachement
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=%s
--%s
""" % (marker, marker)

# Define the message action
part2 = """Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Transfer-Encoding:8bit

%s
--%s
""" % (body,marker)

# Define the attachment section
part3 = """Content-Type: multipart/mixed; name=\"%s\"
Content-Transfer-Encoding:base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=%s

%s
--%s--
""" %(filename, filename, filecontent, marker)
message = part1 + part2 + part3

try:
   smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
   smtpObj.sendmail(sender, reciever, message)
   print "Successfully sent email"
except Exception:
   print "Error: unable to send email"
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "messed up". Is the attachment broken, or just the plain text in the view window?

Comment: You cannot have an attachent of type `multipart/mixed`; that is for additional MIME parts.  You probably mean `text/plain` with `Content-Disposition: attachment`.

Comment: But it would be better to use a MIME library to take care of these details for you.

Comment: there is text in the file but the identation is bad i.e all the lines got mixed up.

Comment: i'll try using MIME library

Comment: Show us how.  Maybe the abridged source of a wrecked message.

Comment: You are not using a MIME library.  You are using `print` with format strings to piece together MIME parts, apparently without fully understanding the MIME spec.  A proper MIME library would let you do something like `message = multipart(plaintextpart("text"),textfile("text"))` and return a properly formatted email message made up from those parts.

Comment: As your file is base64 encoded, it should be transfered "as is" with no modification in it. Is sender system the same as receiver ? If not different systems may have different conventions for end of line ...

Comment: ficheiro = "test.txt"
f = open(ficheiro, "r")
filecontent = f.read()
part3 = """Content-Type: multipart/mixed; name=\"%s\"
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=%s

%s
""" % (ficheiro, ficheiro, filecontent)